# Access 2010 VBA Form Pulling In Table Data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an "Invoices" table, which I run an "Invoices From off of to create invoices for my clients. All my client data; address, hourly rate, etc. is on my "Client Lists" table. The Tables are linked together by a common account/client ID.

I don't want to update general items like hourly rate, address, every time I create an invoice. I am looking to set up an after update event that will auto populate these general items from my "Client Lists" table when I enter the client ID on the "Invoices" form.

```
---Update---
```

Below is the code I am working with, and I keep getting an error "Expected: list separator or).

In normal speak; The service type field on my "Invoices" form, should look at my Service type field, on my Client Lists table, for the same Client ID as Account ID.

```
Private Sub Client_ID_Change()
Service_Type = DLookup("Service_Type", "Client Lists", "Account ID=" & Client ID)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything?

The short answer is:

create a query to represent the data you want. In vba use a recordset to run the query's logic for the ID you've got, then display the returned data in the recordset on your form.

However there's no detail here, as you have little yourself

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of detail, but it's because I didn't even know where to start. Your conceptual information has helped. I can create a query with the info, I guess I don't understand why you can't just reference the table if there is a relationship between client and invoice in place already.  Why must it be a query.

Comment: I'm sorry for being terse. There is a terminology hiccup here. A "query" means an SQL query statement. If you write SQL code and use this as the source for a recordset of any sort (DAO, ADO) this is considered a "query". Ms-access also has queries, which both are and are not the same thing: You can open an ms-access query by double-clicking on it in the navigation pane, or via docmd.openQuery - what this does, is run the SQL defining that query's logic using DAO; Conceptually it is no different to writing a query yourself and running it on a table directly with a recordset.

Comment: Not knowing what your abilities are/were, the simplest answer was to suggest creating a query using ms-access, and to provide some breadcrumbs re what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have been studying trying to learn this.  I have updated my original question with the code I am working with. Hopefully this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error on the dlookup function.

To specify a search criteria (last parameter of dlookup) based on a field that contains a blank space, you will have to enclose it in brackets. Also consider that control names can have blank spaces, but to reference them in vba you must replace write them using underscores.

```
"[Account ID]=" & Client_ID
```

I would strongly suggest you name table fields and form controls without blank spaces.